# create multidimensional array from php select

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, pdo

```
while ($selected_row = $stmt - > fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $tmp_key = $selected_row['tin']; //adding a temp key
    //$tmp_key = $selected_row['tin']; //adding a temp key
    $new_data[$tmp_key]['tin'] = $selected_row['ownertin'];
    $new_data[$tmp_key]['lastname'] = $selected_row['ownerlastname'];
    $new_data[$tmp_key]['firstname'] = $selected_row['ownerfirstname'];
    $new_data[$tmp_key]['ownershipfrom'] = $selected_row['ownershipfrom'];
    $new_data[$tmp_key]['type'] = $selected_row['ownership'];
    $new_data[$tmp_key]['middleinitial'] = $selected_row['ownermiddlename'];
    $new_data[$tmp_key]['suffix'] = $selected_row['ownersuffix'];

    $sudky = (isset($new_data[$tmp_key]['Address'])) ? count($new_data[$tmp_key]['Address']) : 0; //getting the key for student child array

    $new_data[$tmp_key]['Address'][$sudky]['contactflag'] = $selected_row['contact_flag'];
    $new_data[$tmp_key]['Address'][$sudky]['tin'] = $selected_row['ownertin'];
    $new_data[$tmp_key]['Address'][$sudky]['mobile'] = $selected_row['mobile'];
    $new_data[$tmp_key]['Address'][$sudky]['landline'] = $selected_row['landline'];
    $new_data[$tmp_key]['Address'][$sudky]['email'] = $selected_row['email'];
    $new_data[$tmp_key]['Address'][$sudky]['province'] = $selected_row['addressprovince'];
    $new_data[$tmp_key]['Address'][$sudky]['municipality'] = $selected_row['addressmunicipality'];
    $new_data[$tmp_key]['Address'][$sudky]['barangay'] = $selected_row['addressbarangay'];
    $new_data[$tmp_key]['Address'][$sudky]['street'] = $selected_row['addressstreet'];
    $new_data[$tmp_key]['Address'][$sudky]['zipcode'] = $selected_row['addresszipcode'];

}
$new_data = array_values($new_data);
$input = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $new_data)));
//print_r($new_data);
echo json_encode($new_data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Is there a better way to create this multidimensional array without having the duplicate address

Comment: You can use `PDO::*` to fetch and return in a multidimensional array.

Comment: And can you edit and add your table structure?

Comment: how do you use pdo to do that i never done that before @EliasNicolas

Comment: See this http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php, It should fetch all at once, use the `fetch_style` flag to add `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC|PDO::FETCH_GROUP` and in MYSQL use `Group by`... Then you can do `foreach()`

Comment: i wont be able to test it right now but as soon as i can i will send a reply on this comment thank you for the idea

Comment: Please remove this sensitive identification information. Use dummy data or censored data instead.

Comment: @Parfait ok thank you for the warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer this structure of building the array because (at least to me) it's clearer what's where.

```
$new_data = array();
while($selected_row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $tmp_key = $selected_row['tin'];
    // don't write the same data over and over again
    if(!isset($newData[$tmp_key])) {
        $newData[$tmp_key] = array(
            'tin'           => $selected_row['ownertin'],
            'lastname'      => $selected_row['ownerlastname'],
            'firstname'     => $selected_row['ownerfirstname'],
            'ownershipfrom' => $selected_row['ownershipfrom'],
            'type'          => $selected_row['ownership'],
            'middleinitial' => $selected_row['ownermiddlename'],
            'suffix'        => $selected_row['ownersuffix'],
            'Address'       => array()
        );
    }
    $newData[$tmp_key]['Address'][$selected_row['contact_flag']] = array(
        'contactflag'  => $selected_row['contact_flag'],
        'tin'          => $selected_row['ownertin'],
        'mobile'       => $selected_row['mobile'],
        'landline'     => $selected_row['landline'],
        'email'        => $selected_row['email'],
        'province'     => $selected_row['addressprovince'],
        'municipality' => $selected_row['addressmunicipality'],
        'barangay'     => $selected_row['addressbarangay'],
        'street'       => $selected_row['addressstreet'],
        'zipcode'      => $selected_row['addresszipcode']
    );
}
```

Since your addresses are not duplicated, this should produce the desired array structure.

Comment: no i dont have duplicate data the result return is just duplicate

Comment: do i have to change anything in the code because i get `[]` in response from server also i have error in `$newData[$tmp_key]['Address'][] => array(` i had to change it to `$newData[$tmp_key]['Address'][] = array(`

Comment: what i did is change the `new_data ` above to `newData` but then the result is just the same as my previous code the address has duplicate. but i did return the desired structure only there is again the duplicate

Comment: you know what i did a digging in your answers and i found this `if(!isset($newData[$tmp_key]['Address'][$selected_row['ownertin']])) {
        $newData[$tmp_key]['Address'][$selected_row['ownertin']] = array(` what i did is i change it to `if(!isset($newData[$tmp_key]['Address'][$selected_row['ownertin']])) {
        $newData[$tmp_key]['Address'][$selected_row['contact_flag']] = array(` since only `0 and 1`  will the value i think i got it working ok. `can you revert to that answer?`also i will keep on testing is there will be another issue.

Comment: also i tried it like the answer only difference is i added `$newData[$tmp_key]['Address'][$selected_row['contact_flag']] = array(` seems to be ok what do you think? just add that to answer and if dont see any problem i will accept it thank you for the idea

Comment: Generally I always add the index like you've done with `$selected_row['contact_flag']` unless I absolutely know I don't need it. Ultimately the proof is in the pudding, does the code produce the result you want.

Comment: David i tried running it twice last sat and it returned correctly i will have to try it more today to test. can you update the answer and add that one?